# comparison of Fixnum with nil failed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @order = Order.find(@product.order_id)

    if @order.products.count < @order.total_skus   
      if @product.save
        #Dir.mkdir "/home/deploy/katalister/shared/images/upload/images/#{@product.order.order_id}/#{@product.product_id}" if Rails.env.test?
        Dir.mkdir "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/#{@product.order.order_id}/#{@product.product_id}" if Rails.env.development?
        # redirect_to order_path(@product.order.secure_url)
        render json:{status: true, message: "Product received successfully."}
      else
        render json:{status: false, message: @product.errors.messages[:product_id].join(', ')}    
      end
    else
      render json:{status: false, message: "count ok "}    
    end    
  end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. In the first place you should at least ask a question.

Comment: your `total_skus` in `@order.total_skus` is nil.

Comment: yeah, so what i have to do

Comment: You have to handle nil somehow. You can add .to_i method, it will return 0. Or use  .nil?  method and add some logic to do when it is true.

Comment: ok thank you soo much

Comment: Try to use object.try(:to_i), it will not fire any exception

Answer (score 0):

**FixNum with nil** error is raised when you compare **number** with **nil**

In your case total_skus may be nil. So convert  nil to integer using to_i

> @order.products.count < @order.try(:total_skus).to_i

Comment: nil to int equals zero, assume products count is `0`, `0 < 0` or products count is `3`, `3 < 0` is it strange comparasion?, what the point of the zero comparation?